# Cannabis Page Scrape, Awkward layout

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The page I am trying to scrape is https://agco.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=bef894bc0876448fba26333f1de8d370. From this page I am trying to get 5 types of data, Name of dispenser, address, Postal ( Ex.N4K 5N6), Status and Public Notice date.

My problem is I have no idea how to approach this page. I know the data I want is under "_description" but I have no idea what the table element is and the class. When I am searching around the page I get these awkward section of boxes and it is making me think, are the point sectioned off separately? or is the table element and headers just packaged far up and that's why I am not finding them? Any idea on how I can approach this page would be great.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = https://agco.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=bef894bc0876448fba26333f1de8d370


r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')


cannabis =  soup.find( Would put the header here)
```

Comment: [edit] your question and show us one item as per expected output!

Comment: Open the URL in your favourite browser and inspect the HTML source. How you do this varies by browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd


def main(url):
    params = {
        "f": "json",
        "returnGeometry": "true",
        "spatialRel": "esriSpatialRelIntersects",
        "geometry": json.dumps({
            "xmin": -10018754.17139695,
            "ymin": 5009377.085700974,
            "xmax": -8766409.899972957,
            "ymax": 6261721.3571249675,
            "spatialReference": {
                "wkid": 102100,
                "latestWkid": 3857
            }
        }),
        "geometryType": "esriGeometryEnvelope",
        "inSR": "102100",
        "outFields": "*",
        "outSR": "102100",
        "resultType": "tile"
    }
    allin = []
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    for x in r.json()['features']:
        allin.append((x['attributes']))
    df = pd.DataFrame(allin)
    print(df)
    df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)


main('https://services9.arcgis.com/8LLh665FxwX7bxLB/arcgis/rest/services/AGCOCannabisActive/FeatureServer/1/query')
```

Output:

```
     OBJECTID  ...                   PublicNoticeDate
0      147437  ...  From May 13, 2020 to May 27, 2020
1      148101  ...                                  .
2      147508  ...  From Mar 27, 2020 to Apr 10, 2020
3      147176  ...                                  .
4      147840  ...  From Dec 07, 2020 to Dec 21, 2020
..        ...  ...                                ...
780    147940  ...  From Jan 12, 2021 to Jan 26, 2021
781    147691  ...  From Sep 08, 2020 to Sep 22, 2020
782    147791  ...  From Aug 28, 2020 to Sep 11, 2020
783    147250  ...  From May 09, 2020 to May 23, 2020
784    147201  ...  From Mar 07, 2020 to Mar 21, 2020

[785 rows x 13 columns]
```

Comment: How I would I make it go through every single location on the map? and output to a csv?

Comment: you should really add a donation link to your profile :) Thanks!

Comment: ohh sorry late question but is there a way I can add store that are in progress too?